# PC Crashing and booting randomly

Tags: crash, reboot

Ok it has been happening for about 5 months now and I still cant figure out what is causing the crash, It crashes then reboots again randomly. I still have warranty on my PC parts I just cant figure out what one is causing it...

When is crashes it leaves no log in Event Viewer or anything so I have no idea how to determine what the issue is.

**PC SPECS**

- Windows 10
- 250gb SSD
- 2TB HDD
- Ram - DDR4 2400 GSkill
- Motherboard - MSI X99S Gaming 9 ACK
- CPU - Intel Core i7 5820k
- Graphics Card - EVGA GTX 980 OC
- Water Cooler - H110 Corsair
- Power Supply - Corsair RM1000

I have used AIDA64 Extreme to run stress tests on my CPU and Graphics card and i haven't had issues.

Please let me know if I have missed anything

[image]
  <sup>**CPU Stress Test**</sup>

[image]
  <sup>**GPU Stress Test**</sup>

[Event Viewer][3]

Comment: How often does it crash? And how long has it been running? Does it blue-screen and stop, or just restarts like the reset button was pushed / power turned off & on? Windows used to be pretty prone to crashing after a few hours of use, but I'm not sure about the current version

Comment: honestly it crashes when ever it want's to, When it crashes it just turns of then turns on without a blue screen. It has happened about 5 times today 3 times 1 after the other as soon as i get passed windows login.

Comment: Are any of your system's components overclocked? Can you check to see in the Event Viewer if there are log entries relating to the crashes? (If the system crashes software-wise and reboots to recover, there should be.)

Comment: Not sure if it's hardware or windows... Any updated hardware drivers available? Good idea to check cooling & temps, though I'd think the CPU stress test would heat it up to test the cooling too. Tested the RAM? Could try running a different OS for a while and see if it still happens. Like [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com), it can run from a USB or DVD in ram only (live) and run memtest from it's boot menu

Comment: It was happening while my CPU was overclocked but i have reset my BIOS and it continues to happen, The only Critical error i get in Event Viewer is Kernal-Power Event ID 41.

Comment: @Xen2050 If you mean Windows 95, maybe. There's no Windows in this century that couldn't handle weeks or months of being on without issues.

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots of the stress tests i have run they where only run for so long. but i have done longer it's just there to give an example on the temps.

Comment: Well, 74°C GPU core temperature under heavy load is a little on the warm side, but I guess it should be okay. 36-50 °C around the CPU isn't particularly hot at all. Looks like this isn't related to cooling, at least.

Comment: Have you tested your memory? http://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: @TomZych I have tested that a while back ran it till it succeeded 10 times didn't fail once.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The fan speed was only at 28% for the GPU while it was running at max.

Comment: I wonder if maybe the motherboard is simply losing power randomly? Maybe the power supply or a power cable is slightly defective and cuts out now and then? That would have symptoms like this, wouldn't it? Can't think of an easy way to test it, though.

Comment: @TomZych I have had my suspicions about the Motherboard or the power supply. i just have no idea how to test it I don't have a spare 1000watt power supply or motherboard laying around.. i have asked the company for a replacement motherboard they will get back to me on Monday. because its still in warranty. But i was checking if there was any way of fixing it before then.

Comment: If the whole computer was bought pre-built, then maybe you don't have to troubleshoot each part yourself to find out which one (or combination) causes it to crash. The company that sold it might take the whole thing back under warranty & fix it themselves. But they might not find anything wrong either, without knowing how to "make" it crash it's hard to test.

Comment: @Xen2050 That's the thing I built it myself. It wasn't happening for about 3 months. Then it just kept turning off and resting. And it's hard to diagnose not knowing where the issue is with no error log.

Comment: Could try pulling out a part, run & see if it happens, then pull out another part if it still does. Hard to do with cpu & power & video without having good spare parts to swap. I saw a bad motherboard that would cause similar reboots, also after a few months, so motherboard's my first guess (after memtest & stress tests are good), that one would reboot while running linux too, so that's my next testing idea. (ps. using a UPS? Tested it's power output with a multimeter? Saw a few that would drop from line 120V down to 70V for a few seconds shortly after starting)

Comment: @Xen2050 I have not tested it yet with a multimedia how would i do that, since i don't have one i would have to go out and buy one tomorrow morning. Also should I try connecting my PC directly to the wall. Other than an extension lead?.

Comment: I am going to bed now but if anyone has anything else they wish to add so I can try I will check in the morning and reply. thanks

Comment: You mean media for running Linux? A DVD+-RW or DVD+-R works, might just download the iso then right click -> burn, or [see this Q](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172570/how-can-i-create-a-livecd-livedvd-liveusb), basically the same for Linux mint, just [different iso download](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2889) (xfce seems most stable). And any USB (or flash card SD/CompactFlash if your computer can boot it, or have a usb card reader) should work too, [PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) has a good program for windows that should work.

Comment: @Xen2050 ok so i may have figured it out when my pc turns off i have to move the power cord around and it will turn back on, It must be a power supply fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashing and then rebooting could be an overheating issue, especially if this occurs when playing a game that is a resource hog game on your gaming PC. Possible causes of overheating are:

1. Build-up of dust and debris in the fins of the cooling block of the CPU is impeding proper cooling.
2. A messy arrangement of cables in the computer is interfering with air flow.
3. The thermal paste between the CPU and the cooling block is cracked or worn out and needs to be replaced.

If you want to monitor the temperature of your Windows 10 system there are several free CPU temperature monitoring programs available. If it is an overheating issue, you should fix it promptly. An overheating issue can cause computer parts to fail in very odd ways.

Comment: In fairness, CPU overheating should cause a simple thermal *shutdown*, requiring manually powering the system back on once the CPU has cooled down.

Comment: When i stress my CPU it idles on 48C give or take doesn't, And my GPU runs at about 74 when stress testing. And it doesn't Crash at all while doing so.